Showing the stationary distribution of Langevin Diffusion without Fokker Plank (Rosenthal 15.6.9)
Given a standard diffusion:
$dX_t = \sigma(X_t)dB_t + \mu(X_t)dt$
with $\sigma(X_t)=1$ and $\mu(X_t) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\pi^\prime(X_t)}{\pi(X_t)}$
for suitably smooth $\pi$ such that $\int \pi(x)dx = 1$, $\pi(x)>0$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, I am trying to show that the probability distribution with density $\pi$ is a stationary distribution for the diffusion without using Fokker Plank directly. The route suggested by Rosenthal is to show reversibility with respect to $\pi(x) dx$ which implies stationarity.
I understand that a definition for reversibility is $\int_A P^t(x,B)\pi(x)dx = \int_B P^t(x,A)\pi(x)dx$.
My question is, given the diffusion above, is it the case that:
$$
P^t(x,\cdot) = Normal(x + \mu(x)t,t)(\cdot)
$$
for the conditional transition density of the diffusion?
If so, my approach has been to write:
$$
\int_A P^t(x,B)\pi(x)dx = \int_A \int_B \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{1}{2t}\{(y-x-\mu(x)t)^2 - 2t \log(\pi(x))\}} dy dx
$$
I have been unable to swap the integrals and rearrange to get the RHS of the reversibility condition.
Many thanks.

The author seems to call for a heuristic argument (as is (15.6.3)), so here is one; all feedback appreciated. By Ex. 15.3.7(b) we would need to show that $\int P_h(z,.)\pi(dz)=\pi(.)$ for all $0<h<T$ for some $T>0$. Equivalently, since $\pi(dx)=g(x)dx$ we need to show that $\int E^x[f(X_{h})]g(x)dx=\int f(x)g(x)dx$ for all $f$ compactly supported and smooth (these functions are measure determining for finite measures) for all $0<h<T$ for some $T>0$. Following the arguments presented in Ch. 15.6, for all $h$ sufficiently small (so we choose $T$ very small), $\mu(x)=(g'(x)/g(x))/2$ and $\sigma \equiv 1$ we have
$$E^x[f(X_{h})]\approx f(x)+\frac{h}{2}\bigg(\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}f'(x)+f''(x)\bigg)$$
Integrating both sides wrt $\pi(dx)=g(x)dx$ and using integration by parts we get:
$$\int_\mathbb{R}f'(x)g'(x)dx=-\int_\mathbb{R}f''(x)g(x)dx$$
which implies that the term in the parenthesis has zero integral wrt $\pi(dx)$.
